# Custom Fields/Payment Method Ubercart

Tags: ubercart

I have been looking for a way to add a custom payment with custom fields in Ubercart, but have been unsuccessful in my search.

The only module remotely close to what I need was here: https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_custom_payment but it ended up being a flop with a variety of errors popping up after installation.

Has anyone added custom payments and been successful with them?

Thanks!
Matt